# Parse auto-suggestion query results based on app data

Tags: android, parse-platform

I would like to ask if there is any available option to retrieve partial results based on user input in order to help me to find the information need that user has. Actually, i would like to implement an add friend function and i would like while user is typing, the partial results to be shown in a combo box (like facebook).

For example i would like when user types "ad" in the textview to see a dropdown list(or something else) with some results like {adamos,andrew,andy}.

Am using Parse at the backend and i want to feed the dropdown list from there(realtime).

Thanks,
Adamos

Comment: Use AutoCompleteTextView http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example

Comment: Yeah but will it check in app's online parse database or within the local listview data?

Comment: you can run a Async task background and set adapter to the AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: Am a bit confused. How will the parse query called on each character typed. Btw on auto complete textview am used setAdapter()  and i provide the ParseQueryAdapter but it is not accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the rough idea. Change the code according to your convenience.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.autocompleteadapter);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    search.setAdapter(adapter);
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (count % 3 == 1) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        search.setDropDownHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        adapter.clear();
                        // Run you background task here
                        new AutoCompleteEditTextTask()
                                .execute(search.getText().toString());
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    search.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterview, View v,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            search.setText(adapterview.getItemAtPosition(position)
                    .toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @android-mantra for the reply. Actually, i 've used a similar approach to overcome this problem.

Comment: Which handler class are you importing? Java util or Android os?

Comment: Android OS Handler @bluemunch